# How to get output of a child process already running?

Tags: javascript, typescript, process, operating-system, child-process

Lets suppose a child process named "process1.exe" is already running. It is not a process I have created, its already running by some other program.

I want to get its output in my javascript program. Like tapping into the process to get its stdout, err and data etc.

Something like this maybe

```
const child_process = // get the child process named process1.exe somehow

child_process.stdout.on('data', (data: any) => {
        console.log(`stdout from process1.exe: ${data}`);
    });
```

I was able to get if the process if running or not using os commands (windows) like this

```
  exec('tasklist', (err, stdout) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }

    // Parse the command line output
    const isRunning= stdout
        .toLowerCase()
        .split('\n')
        .filter(line => {
            console.log(line);
            return line.includes('process1.exe'.toLowerCase());
        })length > 0;
     console.log('Is running:', isRunning);
    });
```